# jquery dom reload too late

Tags: jquery, dom

I am facing a strange situation with jquery.
I am printing some html to my dom for an action (I know, this is bad but you know...).
Anyhow, I want to put a kind on notification to display when the data are being displayed. So, I do something like this

```
$("#notification").show();
Draw();
$("#notification").hide();
```

Draw does not make any ajax request, it is just data processing and dom construction/display.

My problem is, if I put a breakpoint just before that and I do a step by step, the notification will display just after the $("#notification").show(). However, if remove my breakpoint, my notification will never show.
Also, if I remove my  $("#notification").hide(); the notification will show at the same time the Draw() finished.

It looks like jquery is not applying the show() until it has finished the Draw().

I have also tried this but it does not work (same behavior)

```
$('#notification').show(0, function() {
    Draw();
});
```

**Solution :**
I used slideDown() and slideUp() with callback to make it work (the animation is better than the default show() animation which slides from the top right corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the callback of the show function, then it waits for the show function to finish before drawing.

```
$("#notification").show(function() {
    Draw();
    $("#notification").hide();
});
```

or

```
$("#notification").show("slow", function() {
    Draw();
    $("#notification").hide();
});
```

if you want to control the show speed.

Comment: To clarify why this is needed, JavaScript has redraw buffers to keep from updating things too fast. `show()` is called immediately in the same frame as `Draw()` and `hide()`, causing it to never display in the first place. If we use callbacks, it will redraw, and only when it's done will the callback be executed.

Comment: Great, this works. Also, I don't want any animation (and by default it slides from the top left to it's position). I thought that putting 0 as a first parameter of show() would prevent that. Is there any way to make a show() with a callback without any animation, just display the element ?

Comment: just use the first example and only provide the callback function

Comment: If I use the first example, it still does the animation and the callback is never called :/ I have no error in my chrome console (I am using jquery v1.8.3 if this can help)

Comment: You probably then need to use toggle(true) without callback

Comment: Didn't work either. I found slideDown and slideUp which actually work. Thanks again :)